# gci with LastWriteTime doesn't return the correct file-object

Tags: powershell

I have a File in a Folder with the following `LastWriteTime` Property:

```
LastWriteTime
-------------
08.09.2016 07:46:18
```

Why doesn't any of these command return the File object?

```
gci . | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -like '*08.09.2016*'}

gci . | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -eq '08.09.2016'}

gci . | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -eq '08.09.2016 07:46:18'}
```

My task is to get all Files which were created on 08.09.2016 in a folder recursively and I know how to do that, but my `LastWriteTime` compare doesn't want to work. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `$_.LastWriteTime` is of Type `DateTime` and you are comparing it with string. You need to create the `DateTime` object yourself, like:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("31/12/1900", "dd/MM/yyyy", $null)
```

You may also convert the `$_.LastWriteTime` to string, like:

```
$_.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString()
```

but keep in mind that the results will be different on computers with different culture settings. Option 1 is the way to go. Complete example looks like this:

```
gci . | ? {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq [datetime]::ParseExact("08/09/2016", "dd/MM/yyyy", $null)}
```